# Parse pcap files to sip message in c++

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks, pcap, winpcap

i want to parse some information from pcap file to my project.
I'm creating analizer that can find errors in sip calls. I created the class that can hold such information (not all of them for now). I use Windows and Codeblocks c++ and have installed the pcap library for windows.
What is the easiest way to achieve this ?

```
class Messege
    {
    private:
        int number;
        string cseq;
        string method;
        string callId;
        string source;
        string destination;
        string request;

    public:
        //set
        void setCseq (string newCseq){cseq=newCseq;};
        void setNumber (int newNumber){number=newNumber;};
        void setMethod (string newMethod){method=newMethod;};
        void setSource (string newSource){source=newSource;};
        void setDestination (string newDestination){destination = newDestination;};
        void setCallId (string newCallId){callId = newCallId;};
        void setRequest (string newRequest){request = newRequest;};

        //get
        int getNumber (){return number;};
        string getCseq (){return cseq;};
        string getMethod (){return method;};
        string getSource (){return source;};
        string getDestination () {return destination;};
        string getCallId (){return callId;};
        string getRequest (){return request;};
    };
```

Comment: I've voted to close as "too broad".  Alternatively you may be asking for recommendations for a tool - which would be "off topic".  *You* need to decide how you are going to parse the pcap files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your might want to check out libpcap.  You can parse a pcap file with:

```
pcap_t *pcap = pcap_open_offline(pcap_filename, errbuf);
int link_layer_type = pcap_datalink(pcap);
pcap_loop(pcap, -1, pcap_handler, NULL);
pcap_close(pcap);
```

where pcap_handler is your call back function:

```
typedef void (*pcap_handler)(u_char *user, const struct pcap_pkthdr *h, const u_char *bytes);
```

Find details [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_loop).